# Let $f$ be the function defined by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ for all $-1<x<1$. Then $f'(x)=$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $f$ be the function defined by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ for all $-1<x<1$. Then $f'(x)=$?

Differentiating, we get $\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{n-1}$ which we can rewrite as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n}$. Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x}$, then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x}-1=\frac{x}{1-x}.$$

Is this correct? I am not sure about my lower summation index.

Comment: Seems to be $\sum_{\color{red}0}^\infty x^n$.

Comment: Ahh. Right. Is it when we integrate a series that we add $+1$ to the lower index?

Comment: No, it's that when we differentiate a series we do not capriciously omit terms. @AlJebr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the lower index in your derivative is not corrrect.    $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} = x+ x^2/2 + x^3/3 +...$$

Thus your derivative is $$ 1+x+x^2+... = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}$$